# Nsurl Connection TimeOut

Tags: objective-c

I have Fired Four ASYNCHORONUS Methods at a time and i am not able to know which method is timed out.I want to know which method is timed out .will server give any id regarding which method is timed out.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Store all connections in a caller. In didFailWithError: method you can do comparison to find which connection failed.

**Option 2**

Use associated NSURLRequest to tell what connection does what.

**Option 3**

Use different delegates to tell one connection from another. Same as above but associate every connection with individual NSURLConnectionDelegate instance.

**Option4**

Derive your own class from NSURLConnection. You may introduce ID there or do other fancy things - you are in control.

**Example.**

You create a `NSURLRequest` and store it for later (option 2). Then you create a connection with the request and a delegate:

```
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:delegate:]
```

If you define `connection:didFailWithError:` method in your `NSURLConnectionDelegate` then it'll be called on timeout.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // The request has failed for some reason.
}
```

NSURLConnection allows you to get original request:

```
connection. originalRequest
```

You get the request and compare it with previously saved ones.

Comment: Can you tell me particular method for that nsurl request